# Can a ConstrainedBox lazily refer to to the size of another widget?

Tags: flutter

Sort of like how `flex` in `Flexible` refers to the size of its parent, can a ConstrainedBox constrain size to a fraction of another widget's size instead of absolute values?

Example

`new SizedBox(
  size: ...
  child: new Stack(
    child: new Align(
      alignment: ...
      child: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: new BoxConstraints.relativeToParent(maxHeightRatio: 0.3),
        child: ...
      ),
    ),
  ),
),`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the widthFactor and heightFactor arguments to Align to size your child. If your logic is more complicated, you can use a LayoutBuilder to get the size of the parent widget and use that to build your BoxConstraints.

Comment: widthFactor can only refer to the size of Align's child not its siblings or parents right?

Comment: widthFactor sets the size of the child in terms of the size of the parent.